# App for recording ASIO line in

Tags: audio-recording

I have a PC running Windows 7 and a 4 channel external ASIO audio card. I thought I could record line in with Audacity but it doesn't suport ASIO. What other options do I have? I need a simple lightweight app to do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, Audacity *does* support ASIO, it just can't include it in binary releases because the Steinberg license is GPL-incompatible. But if you [build Audacity and the ASIO SDK from source](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/ASIO_Audio_Interface#Non-distributable_ASIO_support_in_Audacity), that should work fine.

Alternatively, you can use a different DAW. [Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/) is very flexible, supports ASIO and a bunch of other non-free standards out of the box, and is still very lightweight – perhaps not quite as lightweight as Audacity, but still so small that it can't possibly be a problem on a system that can afford running Windows. It isn't free software, but probably as close to freedom as proprietary closed-source software can get.